# Excel VBA to paste values into pivot filter

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to grab a cell value and use it to filter a pivot table. I tried to record a macro doing this but it appears to store the value in the code instead of using a variable (like cell G1).  Any ideas on how to pass a cell value in place of the "cmi" value?

```
    Range("G1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("field").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("field").CurrentPage = "cmi"
```

Comment: ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("field").CurrentPage = Range("G1").Value   ?

Comment: No, I get Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error

Comment: does "field" exist in your filter?

Comment: field is the name of the field I am filtering on.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line with `.ClearAllFilters`.